# Setting an Instance to null

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, garbage

So I've read through JavaScript [Memory Management](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) and a few other articles, I understand there is some garbage collecting daemon that runs on some interval and auto-magically cleans up.

The problem I have is even if I set the object instance to `null` and run a `timeOut` to check null after setting `null` the instance still exists.

Here is the problem using a simple example:

```js
class Animal{
 constructor(name){
  this.name = name; 
 }
}
class Cat extends Animal{
 constructor(name,type){
  super(name);
  this.type = type;
 } 
 renderHTML(){
  console.log(`rendering HTML...`);
  //variable only exists while block is executing...
  let divElement = document.createElement('div');
  //this should be only reference....
  divElement.addEventListener('click',this.testInstanceLife.bind(this));
  divElement.innerHTML = this.name;
  document.body.appendChild(divElement);
  //remove from DOM interface....
  document.body.removeChild(divElement);
  console.log(`there should be 0 references to this instance, since the divElement should be removed after block execution..`);
 }
 testInstanceLife(){
  console.log(this);
 }
}
//init
(()=>{
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
  var cat = new Cat('grumpy','tabby');
  cat.renderHTML();
  cat = null;
  console.log(`this object is now: ${cat}`);
  console.log(`finished executing...`);
 });
})();
```

**Question:** Why does the async timeout and or the instance method still have reference to itself even though it was set to `null` before they both executed?

Comment: A few things here. First, `this` isn't the current object like it is in other languages, but rather simply the object that the method was called upon. For a `setTimeout` callback, `this` won't be the same as the `this` in the parent method. Second, `cat` is a variable that references an object. Setting it to null changes the variable's contents (it no longer references the object), but the object itself is unaffected. Finally, garbage collection is difficult to observe because it is by design supposed to only clean up objects that are no longer used (i.e. no longer observable).

Comment: A simplistic approach to a GC is it removes things that "are not needed anymore". If your instance still does something, it will not remove it. This approach surely is by far not detailed or always accurate, but is a good first guess. For more details, something deeper down in the runtime holds a reference to it (the "thing" that calls the function given to `setTimeout` - again simplified), therefore the GC will not delete it.

Comment: @ASDFGerte yeah I hate the "are not needed anymore" vibe, I mean if I set the `instance = null` the html elements with the methods still can reference the instance... so when I remove the elements from the interface.... and do a manual `element.click()` you would think it wouldn't be able to reference the `this` and it would return `null` but it still doesn't lol. I guess I just have to have faith that when I set the `instance = null` and clear the the html elements that the instance will be garbage collected, right?

Comment: @Cameron `this` is the same since I'm using the js shorthand fat-arrow syntax `=>` so it doesn't create another scope level... yeah I understand cat is a variable but even after setting to `null` which you can see is triggering the instance is still alive and well, even if I remove from the DOM reference `removeChild` the instance is still alive... I guess I just need to have faith in the garbage-collector, right?

Comment: @ASDFGerte and @Cameron, it just concerns me when I'm talking about tables and individuals cell instances... I'm creating like 500 rows by 10 columns so like 5,000 "cell instances", and if the user reloads it creates another 5,000 and so on... I am setting to null after instantiation... but are they lol, just bugs me I can't see, but yet if I clear all rows/cells from a table I can still reference the instance through a method of the `class Cell` or in this example the `testInstanceLife()` method.

Comment: @Jordan: Ah, missed that `=>` syntax, still used to old-style JavaScript :-) The lambda holds a reference to `this` (because your code uses it). Nothing you do to `cat` will affect other references to the same object, and because there's a reference in the lambda, the object won't be garbage collected before it's called and the runtime forgets about the lambda (and the event listener, which also has a reference, is removed).

Comment: @Cameron your saying the `variable` cat isn't the only reference to the `instance`? because I have reference in the lambda w/ the event `bind(this)`?

Comment: You have three references to the Cat instance you create: the wrapper returned by `bind` (which is used for an event listener on a DOM element instead and not thrown away, and thus persists), the reference held by the closure created by your lambda when you pass it to `setTimeout`, and the `cat` variable. The `cat` variable is the only one that changes before the timeout triggers. The GC won't collect an object with (reachable) references.

Comment: @Cameron got it, that makes sense. So say I removed the `setTimeout` and just had the `bind(this)` referencing the `testInstanceLife()` if I `removeChild` of the `divElement` then there should be no reference to it anymore since the element containing the only reference to it doesn't exist, correct? I'll update the code to reflect.

Comment: Yes, though it's theoretically a bit more indirect than that; after the element is removed, it itself (and in turn, the event handler it's holding onto) is still not collected, so it still keeps a reference until it is; however, once it's collected, the number of references is then zero and the GC can collect it. In practice though, usually the GC is fairly smart and looks for references from a few given roots, so on the first pass it will find the DOM element and Cat instance both unreachable right away and dispose them at the same time.

Comment: With your edit, the object should be collected eventually. You can't test this using code, but you can see the effect on memory in developer tools if you do this sort of thing in a loop (memory usage should rise for a while, then drop after a GC, then rise, then drop, etc.).

Comment: @Cameron Haha yeah exactly thats what I meant it's in the garbage-collector's "hands", it still exists but only till the next garbage interval removes it. Would it be good practice then to `null` all instance properties before so while the instance is in the "waiting period" to be destroyed it's only taking up `null` for stored values?

Comment: No, in general that serves no purpose because the instance is still in memory either way until the GC runs. You'd be doing extra work for nothing. The only time you should do this is if you need to explicitly remove a specific reference which would otherwise prevent an object from being GC'd.

Comment: @Cameron ok makes sense. Thanks for the clarification was going crazy trying to test it out and not seeing results lol. Thanks again!